# Peskin-Schroeder time derivative of canonical momentum in Klein-Gordon theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, commutator

In section 2.4 of the book, it seems that the commutation relation

$[\pi(x,t),\phi(x',t)\nabla^2\phi(x',t)] = 2[\pi(x,t),\phi(x',t)]\nabla^2\phi$

is used to verify that $i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\pi(x,t)=-i(-\nabla^2+m^2)\phi(x,t)$ and show that the Klein-Gordon equation holds in the Heisenberg picture for the $\phi$ and $\pi$ operators.

I can't seem to derive this myself.

Using the fact that $[A,BC] = B[A,C] + [A,B]C$, I got $[\pi,\phi\nabla^2\phi] = [\pi,\phi]\nabla^2\phi + \phi[\pi,\nabla^2\phi]$

It seems as though there must be some way to move the $\nabla^2$ on the right term $\phi[\pi,\nabla^2\phi]$ over to give $\nabla^2\phi[\pi,\phi]$, but I can't find any way to do this. Am I on the right track thinking this, or is there a different trick used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I start directly from the problematic commutator. You should be note that I replace $\vec{x}'\rightarrow \vec{y}$ for better readability.
$$
I = \int \,d^3y\: \phi(\vec{y},t) \left[\pi(\vec{x},t) , \nabla^2_{\vec{y}} \phi(\vec{y}) \right] 
$$
I use the fact that the laplacian is acting on $\vec{y}$ to commute it freely with $\pi(\vec{x},t)$.
$$
I = \int \,d^3y\: \phi(\vec{y},t) \nabla^2_{\vec{y}} \left[\pi(\vec{x},t) ,  \phi(\vec{y}) \right] = \int \,d^3y\: \phi(\vec{y},t) \nabla^2_{\vec{y}} (-i\pi \delta(\vec{x}-\vec{y}))
$$
Finally, I use integration by part and integrate
$$
I = \nabla^2_{\vec{x}}\phi(\vec{x},t)
$$